# Ionic 2 Permission Denied on OSX

Tags: macos, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 project I built in a Windows environment. I have just set up Ionic 2 in an OSX environment.

> ```
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI:  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
> 6.4.0
>
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: macOS Sierra
> Node Version: v6.9.4
> Xcode version: Not installed
> ```

But when I run `ionic serve` I get the following error:

```
Richards-MacBook-Pro:theWhoZoo-chat richardmarais$ sudo ionic serve
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`
 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications.`npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)

******************************************************

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

sh: /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat/node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat/npm-debug.log
There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of permissions

```
sh: /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat/node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied
```

Option 1: Change the permission to npm's default directory

Option 2: Change npm's default directory to another directory

Option 3: Use a package manager that takes care of this for you.

For further information follow the link : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Use option 2 not 1.

Comment: I run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`, but I still get the same error.  I also ran `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat`, but still get: `sh: /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat/node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied`. When I check `ionic-app-scripts` with `ls -l`, I do have permission.

Comment: From `/Users/richardmarais` I run `mkdir ~/.npm-global`, then `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`, and then restart the terminal, and from `/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo-chat` (Ionic App), I run `ionic serve`, but still get the same error.

Comment: Now test with a new ionic project.

Comment: Creating a new app works fine now. Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install the package with sudo ?

Comment: I run `sudo ionic serve`. Is that what you mean?